# Terraform secret value not updating

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-secrets

I am having trouble with secret value update. If I recreate azurerm_windows_function_app with new name the new ID is not being updated in secret value. The secret will contain old ID of the azurerm_windows_function_app.

```
resource "azurerm_windows_function_app" "function_app" {
  name                = "function-app"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.xxxx.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.xxxx.location

  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.xxx.name
  service_plan_id      = azurerm_service_plan.xxxx.id

  site_config {}
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "function_app_id" {

  name         = "function-app-id"
  value        = azurerm_windows_function_app.function_app.id
  key_vault_id = var.vault_id

}
```

Comment: ID is the resource ID. this will not change if you recreate the Function with the same name and in the same resource group

Comment: thank you @silent, i have modified my question. If i change my function name and use same secret name, still its not getting updated.

Comment: Have you checked the `version` of your secret? Maybe it's hardcoded with a particular version?

Comment: no it was not hardcoded